# React router - click on card and redirect to a new page with content of that card (card details) using useParams and reacthooks

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

I have created a blog post. Posts are in the card[Event.js] and on click of the button. It should go to the new page and render its card details there. How can I do it using the react hooks and useParams.?
EventList.js ---> is where I'm fetching the data from api
Event.js ---> I'm rendering the fetched data in cards
EventDetails.js ---> It's the card details that should render on the screen when clicked on the post. Right now I have hard coded. the details.

Could someone please help me with how to do this?

//EventList.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Event from "../Event/Event";
import axios from "axios";
import styles from "./EventList.module.css";

const EventList = () => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState("");

  let config = { Authorization: "..........................." };
  const url = "............................................";

  useEffect(() => {
    AllPosts();
  }, []);

  const AllPosts = () => {
    axios
      .get(`${url}`, { headers: config })

      .then((response) => {
        const allPosts = response.data.articles;
        console.log(response);
        setPosts(allPosts);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error(`Error: ${error}`));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Event className={styles.Posts} posts={posts} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default EventList;
```

//Event.js

```
import React from "react";
import styles from "./Event.module.css";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

const Event = (props) => {
  const displayPosts = (props) => {
    const { posts } = props;

    if (posts.length > 0) {
      return posts.map((post) => {
        return (
          <div>
            <div>
              <div className={styles.post}>
                <img
                  src={post.urlToImage}
                  alt="covid"
                  width="100%"
                  className={styles.img}
                />
                <div>
                  <h3 className={styles.title}>{post.title}</h3>
                  <div className={styles.price}> {post.author} </div>
                  <Link to={`/${post.title}`}>
                    <button className={styles.btns}> {post.author} </button>
                  </Link>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      });
    }
  };
  return <div className="Posts">{displayPosts(props)}</div>;
};

export default Event;
```

//EventDetails.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Navbar from "../Navbar/Navbar";
import DetailsImage from "../../assets/Event-Ticketing.png";
import styles from "./EventDetails.module.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import { Link, useParams, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

// let config = { Authorization: "3055f8f90fa44bbe8bda05385a20690a" };
// const baseurl = "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=bbc-news";

const EventDetails = (props) => {
  const { state } = useLocation();

  if (!state) return null;

  // const [title, setTitle] = useState("");

  // const { eventName } = useParams();

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   axios
  //     .get(`${baseurl}`, { headers: config })
  //     .then((response) => setTitle(response.data));
  // }, []);

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   const neweventName = baseurl.find(
  //     (eventNames) => eventNames.eventName === parseInt(eventName)
  //   );
  //   setTitle(neweventName.title);
  // }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <div className={styles.eventBg}>
        <div className="container">
          <div>
            <img
              src={DetailsImage}
              alt="ticket"
              width="100%"
              className={styles.heroEventImage}
            />
          </div>
          <div className={styles.bookingDetails}>
            <div className={styles.nameBook}>
              <div>
                <div className={styles.eventNameHeader}>
                  <h1 className={styles.eventName}> {props.title}</h1>
                </div>
                <div className={styles.genre}>
                  <div className={styles.genreText}>{props.author}</div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className={styles.bookingBtn}>
                <div className={styles.booking}>
                  <Link to="/GeneralBooking">
                    <button
                      className={styles.bookBtn}
                      style={{ height: "60px", fontSize: "18px" }}
                    >
                      Book
                    </button>
                  </Link>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className={styles.venueTime}>
              <div className={styles.dateTime}>
                <div className={styles.dateTimeText}>{props.author}</div>
                <div className={styles.price}>{props.author}</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default EventDetails;
```

//App.js

```
import "./App.css";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./components/Home/Home";
import EventDetails from "./components/EventDetails/EventDetails";
import GeneralBooking from "./components/GeneralBooking/GeneralBooking";
import AllotedSeated from "./components/AllotedSeated/AllotedSeated";
import Checkout from "./components/Checkout/Checkout";

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="App">
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact>
            <Home />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/:title" exact children={<EventDetails />}></Route>
          <Route path="/GeneralBooking" exact>
            <GeneralBooking />
          </Route>
        </Switch>

        {/* <EventDetails /> */}
        {/* <GeneralBooking /> */}
        {/* <AllotedSeated /> */}
        {/* <Checkout /> */}
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Are you rendering these components into a `Router` on specific paths? `EventDetails` would need to be rendered by a `Route` and the `path` prop would need to have match params defined in order for `useParams` to work. The `posts` state should also be located (and passed) from a common ancestor. An alternative could be to use route state and send the specific post data along with the route transition.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the Route to render it. I will update the code if required.

Comment: I have added the App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it doesn't appear as though you've stored the `posts` state sufficiently high enough in the ReactTree to be accessible by component on other routes I suggest using route state to send a specific `post` object to a receiving route.

Event - Update the `Link` to send also the `post` object.

```
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: `/${post.title}`,
    state: { post },
  }}
>
  <button type="button" className={styles.btns}>{post.author}</button>
</Link>
```

EventDetails - Use the `useLocation` hook to access the route state.

```
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const EventDetails = (props) => {
  const { state } = useLocation();

  if (!state.post) return null;

  return (
    // ...render all the post fields available from state.post
    // i.e. state.post.title
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks. Im trying to render the posts {props.title} but its throwing state is undefined? What to do?

Comment: Could you please let me know what I'm doing wrong I'm kind of stuck  @Drew

Comment: @sud Is it throwing state is undefined on the `if (!state.post) return null;` line? You can try to either drop the `.post` bit (`if (!state) return null;`) or provide fallback for `state (`const { state = {} } = useLocation();`).

Comment: I tried using your method. When I click on the card it redirects to that particular page but the content is not being rendered. I have updated the EVentDetails.js code in the question section could you please have a look into it. @Drew

Comment: @Sud Sorry, I thought it was more clear/obvious, but you should be rendering title, author, etc from `state.post` instead of `props`, i.e. `state.post.title`.